# Обработчик неверных команд pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота, в библиотеке pyTelegramBotAPI.
Столкнулся с тем, что необходимо создать обработчик неверных команд.
При вводе пользователем символов, слов, и прочего то есть команд ни как не граничащих с ботом, должен выбивать сообщение предупреждение.

```
words_list = ['/help']

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() in words_list)
def send_welcome(message):
 if message:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Word detected in list!")
 else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Word detected in list!")
```

К сожалению данный код не реагирует на другие случайные пользователем вводы, кроме команды /help. Как сделать так чтобы он обрабатывал любой не верный ввод и выводил ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
words_list = ['/help']

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() not in words_list)
def send_welcome(message):
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Word not detected in list!")
```

Или так:

```py
words_list = ['/help']

@bot.message_handler()
def send_welcome(message):
 message_text = message.text.lower()

 if message_text not in words_list:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Word not detected in list!")
 else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Word detected in list!")
```